# Calling indices in an expression while iterating over a variable number of indices (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I want to iterate over a variable number of indices given by the length of a list, using the values on the list as the ranges. Further, I want to call the indices in my expression.

For example, if I have a list [2,4,5], I would want something like:

```
import itertools

for i0, i1, i2 in itertools.product(range(2),range(4),range(5)):
    otherlist[i0]**i0 + otherlist[i2]**i2
```

The closest I can get is

```
for [i for i in range(len(mylist))] in itertools.product(*[range(i) for i in mylist]):
```

But I don't know how to call the indices from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close already. When you use a `for` statement, I find it best to
keep the target list simple and access components of the target list in
the for-loop; in this code, the tuples generated by product().

```
import itertools

mylist = [2,4,5]
otherlist = list(range(5))

for t in itertools.product(*[range(i) for i in mylist]):
    print(otherlist[t[0]]**t[0] + otherlist[t[2]]**t[2])
# 2
# 2
# 5
# 28
# 257
# ...
```